# Select and compare multiple tabled MYSQL PHP

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get one table data and also want to check other table data is valid or exits or not for example. I want to get user post data who has more then 0 points.

```
SELECT insta_user.*, insta_post.* 
FROM insta_user, insta_post 
WHERE insta_user.points>0 && insta_post.user_id = insta_user.id 
ORDER BY RAND()
```

I don't want to join both tables i just want user_post table data

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result  +

Comment: I update  and and litter bit more details. I want to get users post who have more then 0 points

Comment: use distinct  ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what exactly you mean, but I am guessing that a following query should give you data from only `insta_post` table:

```
SELECT insta_post.* 
FROM insta_post 
LEFT JOIN insta_user ON insta_post.user_id = insta_user.id 
WHERE insta_user.points>0
ORDER BY RAND()
```